# Identify matching Class variables and return the variable name

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, class

If I wanted to use a function to identify if a list of Class variables was contained in a string or variable, how would I go about identifying the specific variable that the text matched.

```
class numbersChecks:
    number1 = "123"
    number2 = "456"
    number3 = "789"
    numberCheck = [number1, number2, number3]

sample = "63D456DF1"

def main():
    for i in numbersChecks.numberCheck:
        if i in sample:
            print(i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So in this example, I can get the 456 back, but how to get the actual variable name back, such as "number2"

The data I am actually dealing with is very very long hex strings, so I am trying to avoid duplicating the long strings into a separated dictionary, such as `{number1:123, number2:456}`

Comment: Why do you need the class, in first place? Why don't just use a dictionary?

Comment: I was importing the Classes into main, they are rather long. SO I was trying to access the class name and see if the class variable matches a return variable from a function

Comment: So you should think of changing the return value of that function. Be more elaborate in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go by index, or with a dictionary:

```
numbers_to_check = ['123', '456', '789']
for index, number in enumerate(numbers_to_check):
    if number in sample:
        print(index)
```

or

```
numbers_to_check = {'number1': '123', 'number2': '456', 'number3': '789'}
for key, number in numbers_to_check.items():
    if number in sample:
        print(key)
```

Third method is to use a enum:

```
from enum import Enum

class Numbers(Enum):
    number1 = "123"
    number2 = "456"
    number3 = "789"

for number in Numbers:
    if number.value in sample:
        print(number.name)
```

Comment: The dictionary seems to be the fastest iterating over the list, I guess I will just need to move the Class variables into single dictionaries to get everything working smoothly. Was looking to avoid the long copy/paste process.